# JasperReports - xls file generation rows and columns are not displayed properly

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I am generating an .xls format invoice bill in Jasper report using Java. The file has been created with the correct values, but the rows and columns are not aligned properly. Below is a screenshot of the output:

[image: Screenshot]

What do I need to do to make the columns align correctly?

Comment: Please explain how this is relevant to NHibernate, or remove the nhibernate tag.

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is not a 'Code this for me'-site.

Comment: What is not aligned properly? Jasper provides pixelperfect exports and uses table columns for this aligment. It looks good to me, the many columns are a side effect of the pixelperfect feature of Jasper. What do you expect?

Comment: @Rakesh Possible duplicate: [empty columns in excel file while export from jasper](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38989643/876298)