# empty columns in excel file while export from jasper

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I am using jasper report 3.7.6. I have a list which i want to export to excel.I am able to export list into excel but there appears many hidden columns and rows in my excel.How to remove such hidden columns and rows?

My code is like this:

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint;  

 JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource=new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lstScoreSheet);  
 String  reportPath=  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/reports/[![enter image description here][1]][1]ScoreSheet.jasper");       

    jasperPrint=JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportPath, getParameters(batchYr),beanCollectionDataSource);
     HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse1=(HttpServletResponse)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();  
      httpServletResponse1.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=report.xls");  
       ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream=httpServletResponse1.getOutputStream();  

       JExcelApiExporter exporterXLS = new JExcelApiExporter();
       exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
       exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, servletOutputStream);
       exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.FALSE);
       exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
       exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
       exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
       exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS, Boolean.TRUE);
       exporterXLS.exportReport();
```

Image of excel file:
[image]

Here Column A,C,E.... are all empty and hidden .I want to remove those hidden columns.

My jrxml code is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ScoreSheet" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="3.897434200000008"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="2104"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="122"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.column.width" value="100"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
    <property name="detectCellType" value="true"/>
    <property name="onePagePerSheet" value="false"/>
    <property name="whitePageBackground" value="false"/>
    <property name="ignoreGraphics" value="false"/>
    <property name="collapseRowSpan" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreCellBorder" value="true"/>
    <property name="fontSizeFixEnabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="maximumRowsPerSheet" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="batchYear" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="date" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="advanceAccHT1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[advanceAccHT1]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="financialHT2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[financialHT2]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="sn" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[sn]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="financialPT1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[financialPT1]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="remarks" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[remarks]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="advanceAccHT2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[advanceAccHT2]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="auditHT2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[auditHT2]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="advanceAccPT1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[advanceAccPT1]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="bcPT1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[bcPT1]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="financialHT1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[financialHT1]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="incomeHT2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[incomeHT2]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="marketingPT1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[marketingPT1]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="costHT2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[costHT2]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="auditPT1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[auditPT1]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="corporateHT1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[corporateHT1]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="corporateHT2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[corporateHT2]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="corporatePT1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[corporatePT1]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="bcHT" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[bcHT]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="regNo" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[regNo]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="studentName" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[studentName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="costHT1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[costHT1]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="incomePT1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[incomePT1]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="costPT1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[costPT1]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="incomeHT1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[incomeHT1]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="marketingHT" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[marketingHT]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="auditHT1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[auditHT1]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="advanceAccPT2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[advanceAccPT2]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="auditPT2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[auditPT2]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="corporatePT2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[corporatePT2]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="financialPT2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[financialPT2]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="costPT2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[costPT2]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="bcPT2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[bcPT2]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="marketingPT2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[marketingPT2]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="incomePT2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[incomePT2]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="49">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="262" y="0" width="273" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[ABC School]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="364" y="30" width="71" height="17"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>

            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="337" y="16" width="124" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Score Sheet]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="16" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="19" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$F{sn}==0?null:$F{sn}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="18" y="0" width="119" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{studentName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="136" y="0" width="49" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{regNo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="184" y="0" width="17" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{advanceAccHT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="200" y="0" width="18" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{advanceAccHT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="217" y="0" width="18" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{advanceAccPT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="717" y="0" width="85" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{remarks}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="234" y="0" width="18" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{advanceAccPT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="251" y="0" width="17" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{auditHT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="268" y="0" width="17" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{auditHT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="284" y="0" width="17" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{auditPT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="300" y="0" width="17" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{auditPT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="316" y="0" width="17" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{corporateHT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="333" y="0" width="18" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{corporateHT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="350" y="0" width="18" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{corporatePT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="367" y="0" width="20" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{corporatePT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="386" y="0" width="18" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{financialHT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="403" y="0" width="18" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{financialHT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="420" y="0" width="19" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{financialPT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="438" y="0" width="21" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{financialPT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="458" y="0" width="18" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{costHT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="475" y="0" width="19" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{costHT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="493" y="0" width="19" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{costPT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="511" y="0" width="23" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{costPT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="533" y="0" width="21" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{bcHT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="553" y="0" width="21" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{bcPT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="573" y="0" width="22" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{bcPT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="594" y="0" width="20" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{marketingHT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="613" y="0" width="20" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{marketingPT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="700" y="0" width="18" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{incomePT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="683" y="0" width="18" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{incomePT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="666" y="0" width="18" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{incomeHT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="632" y="0" width="19" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{marketingPT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="650" y="0" width="17" height="16"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{incomeHT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

My jasper image :[image]

*UPDATED*.

*New question:*

My row overlap problem
[image]

Comment: You should fix your template

Comment: Possible duplicate: [JasperReports - xls file generation rows and columns are not displayed properly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38853765/876298)

Comment: can you explain me more clearly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this situation you must place text fields close to each other.

Look at 2 this examples :

1) In this example your excel export would be incorrect, like in your case.

[image]

2) In this example everything would be ok.

[image]

So, you need to change your template - field position as much as possible close to each other.

**UPDATE**
This is screenshots based on your code.

1) Your code.

[image]

2) My correction.

[image]

Can you see the difference between this two screenshots?

**UPDATE 2**
Try my correction :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.1.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.1.1  -->
<!-- 2016-08-17T14:43:37 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ScoreSheetCAPII" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="b3b3e463-8dd6-416e-a615-42daac244b2a">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="3.897434200000008"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="2104"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="122"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.column.width" value="100"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
<property name="detectCellType" value="true"/>
<property name="onePagePerSheet" value="false"/>
<property name="whitePageBackground" value="false"/>
<property name="ignoreGraphics" value="false"/>
<property name="collapseRowSpan" value="true"/>
<property name="ignoreCellBorder" value="true"/>
<property name="fontSizeFixEnabled" value="true"/>
<property name="maximumRowsPerSheet" value="0"/>
<parameter name="batchYear" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="date" class="java.lang.String"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>
<field name="advanceAccHT1" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[advanceAccHT1]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="financialHT2" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[financialHT2]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="sn" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[sn]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="financialPT1" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[financialPT1]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="remarks" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[remarks]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="advanceAccHT2" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[advanceAccHT2]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="auditHT2" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[auditHT2]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="advanceAccPT1" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[advanceAccPT1]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="bcPT1" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[bcPT1]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="financialHT1" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[financialHT1]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="incomeHT2" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[incomeHT2]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="marketingPT1" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[marketingPT1]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="costHT2" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[costHT2]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="auditPT1" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[auditPT1]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="corporateHT1" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[corporateHT1]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="corporateHT2" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[corporateHT2]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="corporatePT1" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[corporatePT1]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="bcHT" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[bcHT]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="regNo" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[regNo]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="studentName" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[studentName]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="costHT1" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[costHT1]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="incomePT1" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[incomePT1]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="costPT1" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[costPT1]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="incomeHT1" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[incomeHT1]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="marketingHT" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[marketingHT]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="auditHT1" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[auditHT1]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="advanceAccPT2" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[advanceAccPT2]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="auditPT2" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[auditPT2]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="corporatePT2" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[corporatePT2]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="financialPT2" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[financialPT2]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="costPT2" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[costPT2]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="bcPT2" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[bcPT2]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="marketingPT2" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[marketingPT2]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="incomePT2" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[incomePT2]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="49">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="802" height="16" uuid="b3f33d10-d908-4673-bdac-ac2f62e1abfd"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[ABC School]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="32" width="802" height="17" uuid="0e00356f-d1a8-4165-9ebe-0a63c44c6a0a"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[CAP II Level]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="16" width="802" height="16" uuid="bde62bca-3aea-4354-bc85-fa45dcecaf2c"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Score Sheet]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</title>
<detail>
    <band height="16" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="19" height="16" uuid="b5db95ef-b440-499a-a847-bd03fca30eda"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{sn}==0?null:$F{sn}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="19" y="0" width="117" height="16" uuid="183b3143-6880-4820-b530-dd62ca7d74c6"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{studentName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="136" y="0" width="48" height="16" uuid="d0a2e025-370c-40d3-b411-5f6fd5eed8fb"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{regNo}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="184" y="0" width="16" height="16" uuid="20c3c6b0-52c5-4124-81f7-5ed2064f9bbf"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{advanceAccHT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="200" y="0" width="17" height="16" uuid="7cdf00f9-f69f-4167-9a9b-64410aa04397"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{advanceAccHT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="217" y="0" width="16" height="16" uuid="f93971fd-aee2-4315-bea3-8df4a164ade8"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{advanceAccPT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="717" y="0" width="85" height="16" uuid="8684224a-4ebe-44a2-82cb-0cbbab8020ee"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="9"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{remarks}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="233" y="0" width="18" height="16" uuid="04daeb6a-954d-46dd-843d-609ac0b2f453"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{advanceAccPT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="251" y="0" width="17" height="16" uuid="842932fb-bd92-4d12-bb8e-25713df7db8b"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{auditHT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="268" y="0" width="16" height="16" uuid="95cbcd97-be41-497d-b403-993600b5506f"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{auditHT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="284" y="0" width="16" height="16" uuid="05c6721e-e7aa-4ef8-8a40-372a5050f661"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{auditPT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="300" y="0" width="16" height="16" uuid="cd2cad02-67b7-4a54-abee-025c99183a83"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{auditPT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="316" y="0" width="17" height="16" uuid="91d90809-18cd-4c88-b2d5-47fb630d3825"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{corporateHT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="333" y="0" width="17" height="16" uuid="aa685841-a795-4e0e-bc1e-5b64e1fc1ae3"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{corporateHT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="350" y="0" width="17" height="16" uuid="6ee0482c-3db7-4b00-9b73-c6e3d41572c2"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{corporatePT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="367" y="0" width="19" height="16" uuid="190c08ce-84f7-4c73-9d12-a2985557ca33"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{corporatePT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="386" y="0" width="17" height="16" uuid="12b37691-dbf6-4d7c-94d9-67f2a60f0ec0"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{financialHT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="403" y="0" width="17" height="16" uuid="b77c3a90-d01c-4c8b-bce4-589b45e65361"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{financialHT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="420" y="0" width="18" height="16" uuid="9328abd4-60fc-49ad-9dfd-e6428090cb14"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{financialPT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="438" y="0" width="20" height="16" uuid="af7c037a-1cf9-4824-b7f8-7d4a1c908933"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{financialPT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="458" y="0" width="17" height="16" uuid="9c42de03-c7a8-4401-be43-47b3eba26467"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{costHT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="475" y="0" width="19" height="16" uuid="05ee6a0e-8a98-4fe8-8468-d528f6525310"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{costHT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="494" y="0" width="18" height="16" uuid="40fd7021-60d3-4b01-adf7-faac7228e2c2"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{costPT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="512" y="0" width="21" height="16" uuid="fccd0c9e-9106-46ef-af73-e5d23b7a2b20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{costPT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="533" y="0" width="20" height="16" uuid="65540391-9b31-4f54-9e87-4eb04b210b86"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{bcHT}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="553" y="0" width="20" height="16" uuid="ea8b1ae8-9421-437d-9012-89bfcb0d22dc"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{bcPT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="573" y="0" width="21" height="16" uuid="6a00db3f-7d10-4e31-96ca-7029668f6ede"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{bcPT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="594" y="0" width="19" height="16" uuid="e3b69af2-b945-4e2b-ac06-1f691fab220a"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{marketingHT}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="613" y="0" width="19" height="16" uuid="e79789d6-30b1-4fd8-88d2-0231c2473e3b"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{marketingPT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="700" y="0" width="17" height="16" uuid="d901ebb0-2e6d-469a-b813-f9c8fc950026"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{incomePT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="683" y="0" width="17" height="16" uuid="f46ce9d6-2da3-4b0d-897d-b54cc992df37"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{incomePT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="666" y="0" width="17" height="16" uuid="b08e937d-d1b7-42a7-83d0-b2e3965e7eff"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{incomeHT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="632" y="0" width="18" height="16" uuid="b7b95e62-c26f-4166-b971-ade1377e5bc1"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{marketingPT2}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="650" y="0" width="16" height="16" uuid="fa11ebb3-539a-4cb0-8c7b-b9a5073cd331"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{incomeHT1}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Screenshot :

[image]

Comment: I tried your answer but there is still no change in my excel

Comment: Post your jrxml or screenshot of it.

Comment: You haven't fixed what I write you in my answer. Place fileds close to each other.

Comment: i have done like you have said.I have added new jasper image also.

Comment: When i use you answer ,It says:Attribute 'uuid' is not allowed to appear in element 'jasperReport'.

Comment: ok i removed the uuid and  now excel report is almost what i wanted.