# JRXlsxExporter generating improper xls file

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I am using jasper template to generate pdf and xls files. Following is my method which generates xls file.

```
private void exportXls(List<JasperPrint> jasperPrintList, ByteArrayOutputStream baos) {
        JRXlsxExporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
        exporter.setExporterInput(SimpleExporterInput.getInstance(jasperPrintList));
        exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(baos));

        SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration config = new SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration();
        config.setOnePagePerSheet(Boolean.FALSE);
        config.setDetectCellType(Boolean.TRUE);
        config.setIgnoreCellBackground(false);
        config.setWrapText(true);
        config.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenRows(true);
        config.setCollapseRowSpan(true);
        exporter.setConfiguration(config);

        try {
            exporter.exportReport();
        } catch (JRException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

PDF generation works fine, but excel is generated incorrectly as below with several columns merged

[image]

Is there a way to generate excel so that each entry occupies single cell?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [JasperReports - xls file generation rows and columns are not displayed properly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38853765/876298)

Comment: you should fix the report design. Are you using different text field for report period , report date from and to ? if yes , then it is actually causing an issue in your xls export. Try to match text field start and end with the table column start and end value. for example let say you are having text field "Report Period" then it should have width and height matching with your column "Type".Similarly you need to match other textfield in order to remove merged column.

Answer (score 0):

Jasper Reports provides so-called pixel-perfect exports. When exporting to Excel or Word, it uses many columns or pixel-perfect tables respectively to represent the report as it was drawn.

If you want to see all columns, you could export csv files. Those would be without formatting of course.

As far as I know there is no other setting to change this behaviour.